# asp.net core error CS0428 Cannot conver method Group GetService to non delegate type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, attributes

I am doing and ASP.Net Core MVC Application.

I have a Error Attribute as a header of the Methods in the controller.

Here is my Attribute

```
 public class ClientWebErrorAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly bool isPartial ;
        public ClientWebErrorAttribute(bool _isPartial)
        {
            isPartial = _isPartial;
        }

     public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
            {
                IActivityLogging _activityLogging=context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IActivityLogging>)();
                 var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), context.ModelState);
            .......            
                context.ExceptionHandled = true;
            }
 }
```

I need to get access to an Interface and I am using this line

```
IActivityLogging _activityLogging=context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IActivityLogging>)();
```

But I got this error

```
 CS0428 Cannot convert method Group GetService to non delegate type IActivityLogging
```

I have

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

but it is not recognized, is in black...

this is my interface IActivityLogging

```
namespace ClientWeb.UI.Interfaces
{
    public interface IActivityLogging
    {
        Task<List<ActivityLoggingResponseModel>?>  LogError(HttpRequest httpRequest, Exception ex, string typeId);
        Task<HttpResponseMessage?> LogNonError(string message, HttpRequest httpRequest, string typeId);
    }
}
```

In Program.cs I have this

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IActivityLogging, ActivityLogging>();
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Are you missing a `using` on the top of your code file? `GetService<T>` is an extension method. It might live in a namespace that is not included using the `using` keyword.

Comment: Try adding `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with your codes and reproduced your error:
[image]

It seems the error was just caused by the redundent `)` remove it and  there're no complie errors

[image]